# Creating Batch File

Tags: excel, dos, vba

I'm trying to create a batch file that will convert an Excel file to a PDF. Is there something wrong with my command line because it doesn't seem to work:

```
Dim i As Double
Dim sBatchFile As String
ActiveWorkbook.Save
sBatchFile = "C:\test.bat"
Open sBatchFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, "@ECHO OFF"
    Print #1, "ECHO Converting Excel Files to PDF, Please wait..."
    Print #1, "batchpdf C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew_G\My Documents\Office Docs\Schedule.xls C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew_G\My Documents\Office Docs\TEST1234.pdf"
    Close #1

    i = Shell(sBatchFile, vbMaximizedFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the actual content of your batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Converting Excel Files to PDF, Please wait...
batchpdf C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew_G\My Documents\Office Docs\Schedule.xls C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew_G\My Documents\Office Docs\TEST1234.pdf
```

then you need to quote any file pathes with `""` like this:

```
batchpdf "C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew_G\My Documents\Office Docs\Schedule.xls" "C:\Documents and Settings\Andrew_G\My Documents\Office Docs\TEST1234.pdf"
```

But I don't know how to exactly write it with VBA, so maybe someone else can help you with that.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed my problem in CMD but not in VBA.